# list pair of employees that work in same department

Tags: sql, database, oracle

in oracle SQL how can I list pair of employees that work in same department ... my employee table as follow:

```
employeeid  department
    101        2
    102        2
    103        3
    104        3
    105        4
```

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please do your work next time and then come to diagnose issues you have with it.  SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: maybe its not an issue for you but as my beginner skills about SQL it is, so please if you don't want to help back off !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all employees in departments that have multiple employees by

```
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE department IN
(
  SELECT department
  FROM employees
  GROUP BY department
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Or use `LISTAGG` to show the IDs in a list:

```
  SELECT 
    department,
    LISTAGG(employeeid, ', ') AS EmployeeList
  FROM employees
  GROUP BY department
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: How is either of these "solutions" related to listing "pair(s) of employees who work in the same department"?

Comment: @mathguy I didn't take "pairs" as literally as you did.  Certainly your self-join answer is a possible solution, but if there are more than 2 in one department you will get every combination of "pairs" in each department, which may not be what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If your table is called t, you can "list" the pairs of employees who work in the same department with a self-join, like this:

```
select t1.employeeid as employee1, t2.employeeid as employee2, department
from t t1 join t t2 using (department)
where t1.employeeid < t2.employeeid
```

Fair warning: for departments with a large number of employees, the number of pairs grows asymptotically like 1/2 times the square of the number of employees in that department, so you may get a very large number of rows on a "real" input table.

If needed, you can sort the results as needed, for example add this line:

```
order by department, employee1, employee2
```